I have this problem, it says Fatal error: Cannot use $this as parameter in
function before ($this, $inthat)
{
    return substr($inthat, 0, strpos($inthat, $this));
}
function between($this, $that, $inthat)
{
    return before ($that, after($this, $inthat));
}
function after ($this, $inthat)
{
    if (!is_bool(strpos($inthat, $this)))
    return substr($inthat, strpos($inthat,$this)+strlen($this));
}


Fatal error: Cannot use $this as parameter in /home/u550540499/domains/matureguide.in/public_html/application/helpers/global_helper.php
on line **991

We are facing this when we upload my website in hostinger hosting. Can anyone help to resolve it?

See also here. Have you tried anything yet yourself in order to resolve this?

yeh but error still showing

Ok. So what did you try? There are a couple of different potential solutions, as per the duplicate question. One of those should work for you.

$this is a keyword in php to refer self class objects. therefore it is restricted to use as a parameter variable.

function before($thisStr, $inThat) {
$pos = strpos($inThat, $thisStr);
if ($pos === false) {
return ''; // Return empty string if $thisStr is not found
}
return substr($inThat, 0, $pos);
}
function after($thisStr, $inThat) {
$pos = strpos($inThat, $thisStr);
if ($pos === false) {
return ''; // Return empty string if $thisStr is not found
}
return substr($inThat, $pos + strlen($thisStr));
}
function between($thisStr, $thatStr, $inThat) {
$afterThis = after($thisStr, $inThat);
return before($thatStr, $afterThis);
}

i am trying this

You can not use $this because is a reserved var name in PHP. Just change $this to $myThis and it will work.

i will change but still another error we have facing

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'u550540499_pharmain_quiry'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
Filename: mysqli/mysqli_driver.php
Line Number: 202

Backtrace:
File: /home/u550540499/domains/matureguide.in/public_html/application/third_party/MX/Loader.php
Line: 109
Function: DB
File: /home/u550540499/domains/matureguide.in/public_html/application/third_party/MX/Loader.php
Line: 65
Function: initialize

File: /home/u550540499/domains/matureguide.in/public_html/application/core/MY_Controller.php
Line: 19
Function: __construct
File: /home/u550540499/domains/matureguide.in/public_html/application/modules/home/controllers/Home.php
Line: 6
Function: __construct
File: /home/u550540499/domains/matureguide.in/public_html/index.php
Line: 324
Function: require_once

these error will showing now

Ok. Well did you google that error yet, as well? (And if not, why not??) It simply means you gave the wrong username or password for your database connection

P.S. When you have an update for us please [edit] your question rather than putting large chunks of code and error messages in the comments. Code in particular is unreadable when formatted like this, as you can see for yourself. Reference: [ask]. This isn't a chat forum, your question is supposed to show the complete issue in one place. Comments are just for brief clarification requests, not ongoing discussion. Thanks.
